# Have problems in inserting stylesheet in mpdf?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

```
$htmloutput .= $this->renderPartial('sitepdf',array(
                        'model'=>$model),true,true);
                        'sitemodel'=>$sitemodel,
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');
                      $mPDF1->WriteHTML($htmloutput);
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.css').'/form.css');
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mPDF1->Output();
```

When I created pdf using this code, I am getting error message.

```
preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 39815
```

I tried to enter the path manually like "D:/xampp/......." even thats not working

But if I comment the style sheet, I can get the pdf without the styles I implement in it.

But I want to include the stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just inserted the style sheet inside the 'sitepdf' and its working now. like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

now its working but still my prob is, still it occupies plenty of space, I need the pdf to be displayed in less memory.(without the image) I am getting little less than 1 MB. Is there any way to reduce the PDF size further?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the styling in your CSS is supported... try this http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34

Plus also try with a basic stylesheet to just see if it works at all ...

Comment: Mariachi! Even the basic styles are not updating.

Comment: Is there any problem in applying the pat?

Comment: what is the 'sitemodel'=>$sitemodel thing for? If possible then use the defaultParams=>array() to specify styles. I know its not much but i can't think of anything else right now.

Comment: The sitemodel contains the attributes for the page.but the page is too large and as you said it is not accepting any basic styles.

Comment: I inserted the style sheet inside the 'sitepdf' page half of the css properties are working. but its printing in A4 style , any options to change the style.